# HAProxy redirect request from HAProxy load balancer to another load balancer

Tags: haproxy, google-cloud-load-balancer, haproxy-ingress

I have a GCP external load balancer that is only exposed to port 443 and I have HAProxy load balancer that is exposed to many ports. How can I redirect the traffic coming from the HAProxy load balancer to another load balancer so that I dont have to specify the backends.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `http-request redirect`? doc [here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20redirect). otherwise please describe a bit more your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the doc link. I have two load balancer A and B.  A is configured with backends and is cloud provided load balancer. B is HAProxy load balancer. I want to put load balancer B infront of load balancer A such that any traffic coming to B will be redirect to A. Important thing to note is that load balancer B will have no backend servers. So could you guide me how to achieve this?